# Rotate a 2D square about the Y axis and display it in perspective projection using neither DirectX nor openGL

Tags: c++, rotation

I want to have a 2D square rotated about the Y axis and I want to display it in perspective projection using neither DirectX nor openGL.

If you look at the code below you'll notice I am using direct X matrix and vectors stuff - that's just to make things simple here...

Anyways, after you run the drawSquare method you'll see some kind of rotation, especially if you animate the rotation angle, but the projection does not look right.

Can anybody help me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thx guys.

As I said before: DX stuff is just to make things simple:

```
void set3Dto2D( D3DXVECTOR3* a, D3DXVECTOR3& b )
{
    b.x = a->x / ( a->z * .01 ) + 357.f;
    b.y = a->y / ( a->z * .01 ) + 357.f;
}
void drawSquare( HDC dc )
{
    D3DXMATRIX proj, rot;

    // corners of my square
    D3DXVECTOR3 pt1( 1, -1, 1 ), pt2( -1, -1, 1 ), pt3( -1, 1, 1 ), pt4( 1, 1, 1 );

    // rotation matrix
    D3DXMatrixRotationY( &rot, 1.5708f );
    // projection matrix
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( &proj, 45.0f / 180.0f * D3DX_PI, 1.f, 1.f, 100.0f );

    // multiply corners by rotation matrix
    D3DXVec3TransformCoord( &pt1, &pt1, &rot );
    D3DXVec3TransformCoord( &pt2, &pt2, &rot );
    D3DXVec3TransformCoord( &pt3, &pt3, &rot );
    D3DXVec3TransformCoord( &pt4, &pt4, &rot );

    // multiply rotated corners by projection matrix
    D3DXVec3TransformCoord( &pt1, &pt1, &proj );
    D3DXVec3TransformCoord( &pt2, &pt2, &proj );
    D3DXVec3TransformCoord( &pt3, &pt3, &proj );
    D3DXVec3TransformCoord( &pt4, &pt4, &proj );

    // transform 3D points into 2D ones
    set3Dto2D( &pt1, pt1 ); set3Dto2D( &pt2, pt2 );
    set3Dto2D( &pt3, pt3 ); set3Dto2D( &pt4, pt4 );

    // draw the lines
    MoveToEx( dc, pt1.x, pt1.y, NULL );
    LineTo( dc, pt2.x, pt2.y ); LineTo( dc, pt3.x, pt3.y );
    LineTo( dc, pt4.x, pt4.y ); LineTo( dc, pt1.x, pt1.y );
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a 3d cube to rotate a 2D square?

Comment: That's exactly what I want. I want this square to rotate like it was a side of a cube seen from inside.

Comment: Aren't you applying a world-to-screen projection twice? Once with the DX function, and then again with your own simple 3D-to-2D function?

Comment: @Jongware: I am not able to test it right now, but I think,  well actually I am quite sure, the vertices aren't in screen coordinates before the 3d to 2d function. But I'll try it anyway as soon as I can. Thx.

Comment: I've recreated your code in [processing](http://processing.org). Which is a nice tool to fiddle with graphics logic. I've put the code up on [github](https://github.com/smartsystems4u/rotate2DSquare)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are rotating around the Y axis, which will rotate your cube around the "up" vector. You need to rotate around the Z axis.

Also, a transform is an absolute operation so you'll need to increment the rotation angle to start rotating your square.

(after spending some time to reproduce your problem)

First off, you don't need to perspective correct for what you are trying to do so you can go without the line:

```
D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( &proj, 45.0f / 180.0f * D3DX_PI, 1.f, 1.f, 100.0f );
```

The problem lies in your 3Dto2D code. If you change your code from:

```
void set3Dto2D( D3DXVECTOR3* a, D3DXVECTOR3& b )
{
    b.x = a->x / ( a->z * .01 ) + 357.f;
    b.y = a->y / ( a->z * .01 ) + 357.f;
}
```

to

```
void set3Dto2D( D3DXVECTOR3* a, D3DXVECTOR3& b )
{
    b.x = a->x * 100 + 357.f;
    b.y = a->y * 100 + 357.f;
}
```

it should work.

The problem is that you are assuming that the Z component of your vectors remains unchanged after the transform application. This is not the case and therefore your 3Dto2D function yields unexpected behavior. If you replace the devision by the a.z component with multiply by 100 (every z component in your square equals 1 and X/(1*.01) = X*100). You eliminate the dependence on the z component and your function should behave as expected.

Comment: Hi Willem, I am indeed rotating the square about the Y axis. Just like the square was a side of a cube you're looking from inside and this cube is rotating around you.

Comment: ah, I thought you simply wanted a stationary rotating square.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me again. Probably because of my english. I am not trying to animate it. Not yet. I just want to see the square turned at a certain degree.

Comment: Hi Willem, I thank you for the code, I tested it in Processing and well, that's cool but not what I'm looking for. The way you wrote the code, you get kinda Orthographic projection and I want Perspective projection, that's why I have to divide X and Y by Z. Anyways I thank you again for trying to help me.

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit confused now what your actual problem is. I thought you had problems getting the rotation right. Adding perspective correction is a minor issue which is seperate from the rotation. Please specify clearly what exactly the problem is with which you need help.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I did not explained my problem completely. Imagine a cube built around the point 0,0,0. the camera is inside this cube. It turns around it about the Y axis that goes through this center point. That's what I want to draw, but instead the whole cube, I just want to draw the side that is in front of the camera using perspective projection without using either openGL nor DirectX. Hope it's clear now :( Thanks for your help.